# + is not getting added while saving international number

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.mywebsite.com/setnumber.asmx?myNumber=%@", myNumber.text]
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

When I `NSLog`, url I see below

```
www.mywebsite.com/setnumber.asmx?myNumber=+96512345678
```

But when I look at the database, I do not see `+`. I just see number as 96512345678
Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an URL, `+` means  (space). In order to transmit the character, you'll have to URL-encode it.

Unfortunately, the method you are using doesn't URL-encode strings hard enough; instead you need something along the lines of this:

```
NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
  NULL,
  (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
  NULL,
  (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
  kCFStringEncodingUTF8
);
```

---

To de-code use

```
NSString *unencodedUrlString = [@"http://www.demo.com/2%2C7"
stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I am doing that... `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Comment: Unfortunately, due to a bug, that method doesn't do it hard enough.

Comment: so I have to use replace all function? and replace + to %2B

Comment: this is giving me output text as %2B965%2012345678

Comment: any update why I am getting string in DB as `%2B965%2012345678` after encoding? **Does this mean while showing the data, I need to de-code?**

Comment: @FahimParkar: Clearly.

Comment: I am not getting... could you please let me know how to de-code?

Comment: NSString *unencodedUrlString = [@"http://www.demii.com/demo/dooponz/admin/index.php/chat/new_message/4/1/you/2%2C7" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; this did the trick